# Timeout Issue When Downloading from AWS EC2 to iOS app

Tags: swift, amazon-ec2, https, ios9, kitura

I have a custom server written in Swift, using Kitura (http://www.kitura.io), running on an AWS EC2 server (under Ubuntu 16.04). I am securing it using a CA signed SSL certificate (https://letsencrypt.org), so I can use https to connect from the client to the server. The client runs natively under iOS (9.3). I use URLSession's on iOS to connect to the server.

I'm having client timeout problems when I make multiple largish downloads to the iOS client back to back. The timeouts look like:

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out."
>   UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://,
>   _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.,
>   _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, NSUnderlyingError=0x7f9f23d0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "(null)"
>   UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102}}}

On the server, the timeouts always occur at the same place in the code-- and they cause the specific server request thread to block and never recover. The timeouts occur just as the server thread calls the Kitura `RouterResponse` `end` method. i.e., the server thread blocks when it calls this `end` method. In light of this, it is not surprising that the client app times out. This code is open-source, so I'll link to where the server blocks: https://github.com/crspybits/SyncServerII/blob/master/Server/Sources/Server/ServerSetup.swift#L146

The client-side test that fails is: https://github.com/crspybits/SyncServerII/blob/master/iOS/Example/Tests/Performance.swift#L53

I am not downloading from something like Amazon S3. The data is is obtained on the server from another web source, and then downloaded to my client via https from the server running on EC2.

As an example, it's taking 3-4 seconds to download 1.2 MB of data, and when I try 10 of these 1.2 MB downloads back to back, three of them timeout. The downloads occur using a HTTPS GET request.

One thing of interest is that the test that does these downloads first does uploads of the same data sizes. I.e., it does 10 uploads at 1.2 MB each. I've seen no timeout failures with those uploads.

Most of my requests *do* work, so this does not appear to be simply a problem with, say, an improperly installed SSL certificate (I've checked that with https://www.sslshopper.com). Nor does it seem to be a problem with improper https setup on the iOS side, where I've got `NSAppTransportSecurity` setup in my app .plist using Amazon's recommendation (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/preparing-your-apps-for-ios-9/).

Thoughts?

**Update1:**
I just tried this with my server running on a local Ubuntu 16.04 system, and using a self-signed SSL certificate-- other factors remaining the same. I get the same issue coming up. So, it seems clear this does **not** relate to AWS specifically.

**Update2:**
With the server running on the local Ubuntu 16.04 system, and without using SSL (just a one line change in the server code and the use of http as opposed to https in the client), the issue is **not** present. The downloads occur successfully. So, it seems clear that this issue **does** relate to SSL.

**Update3:**
With the server running on the local Ubuntu 16.04 system, and using the self-signed SSL certificate again, I used a simple `curl` client. In order to simulate the test I've been using as closely as possible, I interrupted the existing iOS client test just as it was beginning to start its downloads, and restarted using my `curl` client-- which used the download endpoint on the server to download the same 1.2MB file 20 times. The error did *not* replicate. My conclusion is that the problem stems from an interaction between the iOS client and SSL.

**Update4:**
I now have a simpler version of the iOS client reproducing the issue. I'll copy it in below, but in summary, it uses `URLSession`'s and I see the same timeout issue (the server is running on my local Ubuntu system using the self-signed SSL certificate). When I disable the SSL usage (http and no SSL certificate used on the server), I do *not* get the issue.

Here's the simpler client:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {        
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        download(10)
    }

    func download(_ count:Int) {
        if count > 0 {
            let masterVersion = 16
            let fileUUID = "31BFA360-A09A-4FAA-8B5D-1B2F4BFA5F0A"

            let url = URL(string: "http://127.0.0.1:8181/DownloadFile/?fileUUID=\(fileUUID)&fileVersion=0&masterVersion=\(masterVersion)")!
            Download.session.downloadFrom(url) {
                self.download(count - 1)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

// In a file named "Download.swift":

```
import Foundation

class Download : NSObject {
    static let session = Download()

    var authHeaders:[String:String]!

    override init() {
        super.init()
        authHeaders = [
            <snip: HTTP headers specific to my server>
        ]
    }

    func downloadFrom(_ serverURL: URL, completion:@escaping ()->()) {

        let sessionConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        sessionConfiguration.httpAdditionalHeaders = authHeaders

        let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfiguration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)

        var request = URLRequest(url: serverURL)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"

        print("downloadFrom: serverURL: \(serverURL)")

        var downloadTask:URLSessionDownloadTask!

        downloadTask = session.downloadTask(with: request) { (url, urlResponse, error) in

            print("downloadFrom completed: url: \(String(describing: url)); error:  \(String(describing: error)); status: \(String(describing: (urlResponse as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode))")
            completion()
        }

        downloadTask.resume()
    }
}

extension Download : URLSessionDelegate, URLSessionTaskDelegate /*, URLSessionDownloadDelegate */ {
    public func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Swift.Void) {
        completionHandler(URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition.useCredential, URLCredential(trust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!))
    }
}
```

**Update5:**
Whew! I'm making progress in the right direction now! I now have a simpler iOS client using SSL/https and not causing this issue. The change was suggested by @Ankit Thakur: I'm now using `URLSessionConfiguration.background` instead of `URLSessionConfiguration.default`, and that seems to have been what makes this work. I am not sure why though. Does this represent a bug in `URLSessionConfiguration.default`? e.g., my app is not explicitly going into the background during my tests. Also: I'm not sure how or if I'm going to be able to use this pattern of code in my client app-- it seems like this usage of `URLSession`'s does not let you change the `httpAdditionalHeaders` after you create the URLSession. And it appears the intent of the `URLSessionConfiguration.background` is that the `URLSession` should live for the duration of the app's lifetime. This is a problem for me because my HTTP headers can change during a single launch of the app.

Here's is my new Download.swift code. The other code in my simpler example remains the same:

```
import Foundation

class Download : NSObject {
    static let session = Download()

    var sessionConfiguration:URLSessionConfiguration!
    var session:URLSession!
    var authHeaders:[String:String]!
    var downloadCompletion:(()->())!
    var downloadTask:URLSessionDownloadTask!
    var numberDownloads = 0

    override init() {
        super.init()
        // https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlsessionconfiguration/1407496-background
        sessionConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "MyIdentifier")

        authHeaders = [
            <snip: my headers>
        ]

        sessionConfiguration.httpAdditionalHeaders = authHeaders

        session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfiguration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)
    }

    func downloadFrom(_ serverURL: URL, completion:@escaping ()->()) {
        downloadCompletion = completion

        var request = URLRequest(url: serverURL)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"

        print("downloadFrom: serverURL: \(serverURL)")

        downloadTask = session.downloadTask(with: request)

        downloadTask.resume()
    }
}

extension Download : URLSessionDelegate, URLSessionTaskDelegate, URLSessionDownloadDelegate {
    public func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Swift.Void) {
        completionHandler(URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition.useCredential, URLCredential(trust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!))
    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
        print("download completed: location: \(location);  status: \(String(describing: (downloadTask.response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode))")
        let completion = downloadCompletion
        downloadCompletion = nil
        numberDownloads += 1
        print("numberDownloads: \(numberDownloads)")
        completion?()
    }

    // This gets called even when there was no error
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {
        print("didCompleteWithError: \(String(describing: error)); status: \(String(describing: (task.response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode))")
        print("numberDownloads: \(numberDownloads)")
    }
}
```

**Update6:** 
I see now how to deal with the HTTP header situation. I can just use the `allHTTPHeaderFields` property of the URLRequest. Situation should be basically solved!

**Update7:**
I may have figured out why the background technique works:

> Any upload or download tasks created by a background session are
>   automatically retried if the original request fails due to a timeout.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurlsessionconfiguration/1408259-timeoutintervalforrequest

Comment: code looks good for client side. Would you try SessionConfiguration to background instead of default. `let sessionConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration.default`

Comment: Thanks for the idea. At least in my code, this is taking quite a bit of restructuring to even try this. E.g., when you switch to using background, you can no longer use a closure-- you have to use a delegate. The thing that has me stumped right now, after working on this for a while is-- I'm not getting the response headers I expect in the delegate methods. That is, in `func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?)` `task.response` doesn't contain the headers I expect.

Comment: try using wireshark. You can then confirm the request header and response in wireshark and then debug the code. May be some request header is the problem, check content-type or other request headers.

Comment: @AnkitThakur -- I've got some progress now-- see **Update 5** above-- I'm using `URLSessionConfiguration.background` in an example, as you suggested, and the issue is not happening. Thanks for that. I'm curious about what led you to this suggestion in the first place. Have you seen other cases where such timeouts were happening? Given that my app was not (to my understanding) going into the background, I find it strange that `URLSessionConfiguration.background` would fix the problem. Is this a bug in `URLSessionConfiguration.default`?

Comment: Oh, and @AnkitThakur, please add your suggestion about `URLSessionConfiguration.background` in as the answer to this question, and I'll mark it as the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

code looks good for client side. Would you try `SessionConfiguration` to `background` instead of `default`. `let sessionConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration.default`.

There are many scenarios, where I have found `.background` is working much better than `.default`.
e.g. timeout, GCD support, background download.

I always prefer to use `.background` session configuration.

Comment: Thanks again, @AnkitThakur!